# can't import matplotlib.pyplot; DLL load failed

Tags: python, matplotlib, dll

Having a problem importing matplotlib.pyplot into Jupyter notebook.

I uninstalled matplotlib (and seaborn) and reinstalled them again. But that didn't solve the problem.

The exact code however works in my second computer without problems.

I researched stackoverflow, and tried one thing that was suggested (please see bottom of post) - that still gave the exact same error.

Here's some relevant info

```
Platform : win-64, Windows 7 Enterprise
Conda version : 4.4.7
Conda-build version : 3.0.27
Python version : 3.6.4.final.0
JupyterLab :  v0.27.0
Matplotlib version 2.1.2
```

Here's what I am trying to run:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
```

I get the error shown below:

[Pyplot_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZC9cf.png)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
        <ipython-input-1-d2e7a3f2c9b4> in <module>()
        1 import pandas as pd
        2 import numpy as np
        ----> 3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        4 import seaborn as sns
        5 get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')

        ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in <module>()
        30 from cycler import cycler
        31 import matplotlib
        ---> 32 import matplotlib.colorbar
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        33 from matplotlib import style
        34 from matplotlib import _pylab_helpers, interactive

        ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py in <module>()
        34 import matplotlib.collections as collections
        35 import matplotlib.colors as colors
        ---> 36 import matplotlib.contour as contour
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        37 import matplotlib.cm as cm
        38 import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

        ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py in <module>()
        19 import matplotlib.colors as colors
        20 import matplotlib.collections as mcoll
        ---> 21 import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        22 import matplotlib.text as text
        23 import matplotlib.cbook as cbook

        ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py in <module>()
        56 
        57 import matplotlib
        ---> 58 from matplotlib import afm, cbook, ft2font, rcParams, get_cachedir
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        59 from matplotlib.compat import subprocess
        60 from matplotlib.fontconfig_pattern import (

        ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I get the same error when I try

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('tkagg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Comment: I think someone had a similar issue recently, also using anaconda. In any case what is happening here is that the binaries for matplotlib are not correctly installed or are incompatible to the versions of python or some other dependency. In the end this might be a problem at anaconda's side, not providing the matching versions.

Comment: Does matplotlib even have a version 2.1.2?

Comment: @DavidG My `matplotlib.__version__` tells me `2.1.2`, so I guess it does. See [https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/releases](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/releases).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Well, shows how much I know :-) though there isn't any new documentation is there? The only reference to 2.1.2 I can find is on [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/matplotlib)... Nevermind, just seen your comment edit